# Running programs easily from a command line on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, path

Linux allows me to have a short system path by placing binaries in just a few locations. I don't have to edit the path because I just installed a new application, and I don't have to hunt for applications I want to run. How can I, with PowerShell as the program I use to launch programs from, accomplish the same thing on Windows (Vista)?

Comment: unfortunately this is not programming related.

Comment: I'd have to disagree, it may not be Computer Science related, but it is Software Engineering related.  I have to deal with adding stuff to my path as a programmer frequently.

Comment: It's more like configuration. Should be on ServerFault.

Comment: With 119 rep he can't use serverfault for now ...

Comment: This is more like a .Net question.  He is asking about Powershell with a .net platform and may get better responces from programmers then admins

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista has symlinks now via [mklink](https://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html).

Perhaps you could setup a "C:\bin" folder and generate symlinks to point back to the original binaries. That is assuming that Windows Vista's symlinks work similarly to the ones in Linux. [Here's a short tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: They do work similarly but you have another problem, then. Many programs assume their data or libraries to be in the directory they are installed in (as for libraries this is also an artifact of LoadLibrary). So by symlinking just the exe to another path you are starting C:\bin\blah.exe which thn fails to load any of its data/libraries because they're not in C:\bin but rather in %ProgramFiles%\Blah. So it's a rather brittle solution. Windows is, after all, an entirely different environment than Unix. Trying to have it both ways usually doesn't work out properly.

Answer (score 2):

Many programs create an application paths entry in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths). For those applications, you can start them like so:

```
PS> Start-Process <application name>
PS> Start-Process excel
```

If you don't have PowerShell V2, which provides [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process), you can use the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) on V1.

Comment: The PSCX link still works (redirects to a CodePlex archive), but perhaps move it to [the GitHub one](https://github.com/Pscx/Pscx)?

Comment: PSCX is on GitHub here - https://github.com/pscx/pscx  But unless you're using PS v1 (very unlikely) you can just use the built-in `Start-Process` command.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like adding a few directories to your `path` environmental variable might help. From the command prompt you can view all environmental variables with the set command. Then you can cut and paste your path and use `set` again to add to it.

If you prefer the GUI route, right click on *My Computer* → *Properties* → (in Windows Vista and Windows 7 go to *"Advanced System Settings"* on the left. In Windows XP, skip this step) → *Advanced Tab* → At the bottom there is an <kbd>Environmental Variables</kbd> button.

When something is invoked from the command line, Windows checks in all the directories marked in the path first. After your application directory is in the path, you can execute it without fully qualifying your path.

Comment: In Vista and Windows 7 you can get there even quicker by just searching for "environment" on the start menu, as there is an entry "Edit environment variables for your account"

Answer (score 1):

You could always add a .cmd file as an alias.

Comment: Rather than use .cmd as an alias, you can just use PowerShell's built-in aliasing mechanism:

Set-Alias Fiddler 'C:\Program Files\Fiddler2\Fiddler.exe'

Answer (score 0):

I install applications into `C:\bin`.

Answer (score 0):

Using specifically PowerShell you can just create aliases for programs you want to start. I doubt that this is actually less work than editing the `PATH` environment variable, though.